# What is the professional way of using navigationDestination in a SwiftUI app that has multiple tabs and complex navigation?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigation, swiftui-navigationstack

I want to build an application that has different tabs and each tab has access to multiple views. Currently, this is how I handle it. I have created a singleton class that has all the information for routing in it. and since each route can have its own specific enums added to its array, I can limit access on different routes. and it gives me flexibility in performing certain actions.

```swift
final class AppData: ObservableObject {
    static var shared = AppData()
    
    // Active Tab
    @Published var activeTab: Tab = .home
    
    // Map Tab
    @Published var mapNavStack: [MapStack] = []
    
    // Leaderboard Tab
    @Published var leaderboardNavStack: [LeaderboardStack] = []
    
    // Home Tab
    @Published var homeNavStack: [HomeStack] = []
    @Published var homeActiveTab: HomeTab = .forYou
    
    // My Profile Tab
    @Published var myProfileNavStack: [MyProfileStack] = []
    @Published var myProfileActiveTab: MyProfileActiveTab = .stats
    @Published var showEditProfile: Bool = false
    
    // Authentication Tab (Only before sign-in)
    @Published var authNavStack: [AuthStack] = []
    
    func reset() {
        self.activeTab = .home
        
        self.homeNavStack.removeAll()
        self.mapNavStack.removeAll()
        self.leaderboardNavStack.removeAll()
        self.authNavStack.removeAll()
        
        self.myProfileNavStack.removeAll()
        self.myProfileActiveTab = .stats
        self.showEditProfile = false
    }
}
```

For example, LeaderboardStack enum looks like this:

```swift
enum LeaderboardStack: Hashable {
    case userProfile(id: String)
    case userConnections(userId: String, initTab: UserConnectionsTab)

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        switch self {
        case .userProfile(let id):
            hasher.combine("userProfile")
            hasher.combine(id)
        case .userConnections(let userId, let tab):
            hasher.combine("userConnections")
            hasher.combine(userId)
            hasher.combine(tab)
        }
    }
}
```

So leaderboard screen can only navigate to userProfile and userConnections.
And finally to make this all work I'm using this view modifier on LeaderboardView (Where I have Leaderboards' `NavigationStack`)

```swift
.navigationDestination(for: LeaderboardStack.self) { link in
    switch link {
    case .userProfile(let id):
        UserProfileView(id: id)
    case .userConnections(let userId, let initTab):
        UserConnectionsView(userId: userId, activeTab: initTab)
    }
}
```

But the problem is if there is a common screen that every tab can access I need to duplicate the code. But the bigger problem is when I want to navigate using `NavigationLink(value:label:)`, Since I don't know which tab it's going to be in I can't use it. for example, I can't hardcode `LeaderboardStack.userProfile(id: "THEID")` because it might be in the **Home Tab** so I'm being forced to append directly to the stack arrays based on the activeTab value.
I'm very new to Swift and SwiftUI. any help is much appreciated.
How do real-world applications handle complex routings?

Comment: I don't know that there many real world complex routing apps out there. SwiftUI is still very new and has a ton of bugs. Add a `goTo` `func` to `AppData` you can route from there I have used it a few times when adding deep linking but there are inherit dangers for having your routing in a `class`. think about UX too, how many large apps out there do you actually see "jumping" tabs, I dont think that is a real thing in successful apps.

Comment: It'd be worth reading the HIG, which strongly discourages this.  From the intro to tab view: "Make sure the controls within a pane affect content only in the same pane. Panes are mutually exclusive, so ensure they’re fully self-contained"

Comment: the `goTo` func would work but it's not solving the problem that I'm unable to use NavigationLink in Views because I'm not sure which tab they are going to end up in. By **jumping** do you mean between tabs or between different views within a tab? Can you please explain what are the potential dangers? any source that I can get some knowledge/experience on these? @loremipsum thanks in advance.

Comment: All panes in my app are self-contained. However, I need to implement deep linking to navigate users to specific views. How can I achieve this in SwiftUI without compromising the independence of each pane? @flanker

Comment: Jumping between tabs, it is not good UX. If I am on  home and want to see the leaderboard from some button in home it shouldn’t “jump” to the leaderboard tab. Yes you cant use NavigationLink to jump between tabs. That setup isn’t a thing. But generally home should deal with home stuff not leaderboard stuff.

Comment: The dangers come from using an object to handle view state come from the inefficiencies. Value types are much more precise and don’t cause complete invalidations.

Comment: Notice how Apple only uses value types for view State https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-user-interface-state